# SpringBoot app Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7

I have a SpringBoot app. I am checking the logs, and I see this error and I have no idea where it comes from

```
2018-01-30 11:08  [http-nio-1234-exec-1] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error processing request
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet.getArchiveEntries(JarWarResourceSet.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:1027)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap(Mapper.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some jar file in your bandle is corruped. Check that all your jar files included in your application (for instance your dependencies) can be opened with some zip archiver application.